# How to add zxing in android studio?

Tags: android, zxing

When I add

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.0'
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
  compile files('./libs/zxing/core.jar')
}
```

in build.gradle in both cases it shows error in manifest file

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'CaptureActivity'
```

Manifest File is as

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When i add

```
com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar
```

in libs folder then Manifest error is solved but it gives

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
```

Is it necessary to add captureactivity.jar in libs, if not then how to solve manifest error.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: `CaptureActivity` is not part of the core library, and is not meant to be used as if it is a library. It is in `android/`, and you can reuse parts of that code for your own app, but you should be writing your own app from scratch rather than cloning the Barcode Scanner app, which seems to be your starting point here. Please read https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/License-Questions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking CaptureActivity is part of core Lib. First i have to understand the android/ project and modify the code according to requirement. Am i right ?

Comment: I'd say you should write your own scanning app, rather than try to start from Barcode Scanner. 95% of the time people "modify `android/`" they end up cloning the UI, which is not permitted, and messing with our Intents. As long as you know enough to not do that, OK.

Comment: I mean i will use android/ only to understand the logic and functionality not anything else. Thanks again.